# Нахождения слова по частичному совпадению

Tags: python, строки

Допустим, у меня есть слово "корова", и оно находится в черном списке.
Когда пользователь вводит слово "корова", выводится сообщение что слово в ч.с.

Проблема в том, что, когда он вводит "коров" или "коро", то ввод не определяется как слово из черного списка. Как можно находить такие слова опираясь на частичное совпадение?

```
word = ''
blacklist = []
for i in list1:
    blacklist.append(i['words'].lower())
wlist = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(' \t\n,.'), word.lower().split()))
if any(x in wlist for x in blacklist):
```

Таков мой код сейчас и он делает так, что, если "корова" в ч.с., и пользователь вводит слово "молоко корова", код выдает сообщение о том, что слово находится в ч.с.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так:

```
word = "koro" #input().lower()
blacklist = ['korova', 'drova']

if any(word == w[:len(word)] for w in blacklist):
    print(BLACKLIST!)
```

Comment: Я написал k, в поле слова и оно пишет, что это блеклист, с этой программой, половина алфавита недоступна.

Comment: ну так это ваше требование было - чтоб и кусок слова мог бы учитываться в списке
тогда уточните - что именно нужно - где понимать, что это корова - "коров", "коро", "кор", "ко", "к"? сколькими буквами от конца слова ограничиться? там правка будет примитивной

Comment: Мне - ничего не нужно было, а так, это фиксится отниманием от длины слова 1-2-х чисел.

Comment: @Utsiye он сделал то о чем я просил)

Comment: any(w.startswith(word) for w in blacklist)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете обрезать строку и если все символы, кроме последнего и предпоследнего наблюдаются в строке, то выводить сообщение:

```
word = input()
blacklist = ['Korova']
for item in blacklist:
    if item in word or item[:-1] in word or item[:-2] in word:
        print('BLACKLIST!')
```